# Compatibility in Real numbers?

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

I'm reading [Good Math by Mark Chu-Carroll](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785335) and it says,

> - "$\le$" is compatiable with "+" and "*":
>
>   1. ...
>   2. if *x* $\le$ *y*, then for all *z* where *0* $\le$ *z*, (*x* * *z*) $\le$ (*y* * *z*).
>   3. if *x* $\le$ *y*, then for all *z* where *z* $\le$ *0*, (*x* * *z*) $\le$ (*y* * *z*).

Is that 3. true?

When

*x* = -2, *y* = -1, and *z* = -1

Then

(-2 * -1) $\le$ (-1 * -1) ?

Comment: The sign is reversed.  Example, $3\leq 5$ but $(3\cdot (-1))\leq (5\cdot (-1))$ is false.  Rather, $(3\cdot (-1))\color{red}{\geq}(5\cdot (-1))$.  Multiplication by a negative "flips" the inequality sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. Either there is a typo in the book, or there is a typo in your transcription.

For example, $-2 \leq 3$, and $-5 \leq 0$, but $$-5 \times -2 = 10 \not\leq -15 = -5 \times 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is reversed.  It should read

> 3. if *x* $\le$ *y*, then for all *z* where *z* $\le$ *0*, (*y* * *z*) $\le$ (*x* * *z*).
>      Alternately, you can reverse the $\le$ to $\ge$ and keep $x$ and $y$ where they are.